# The set of bounded sequences has a subset of strictly positive sequences, is this open in X?

Tags: real-analysis

Let's consider the set $X$ of bounded sequences in $\Bbb R$.
and also consider the subset of strictly positive sequences 
$$
A = \{(x_n)∈ X | x_n>0\}
$$
Is $A$ open in $X$? I need to prove this but having a hard time.

Comment: Format your question using mathjax.  Show us what work you have already done.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not open in the $\sup$-norm, which is the commonly used one.
Consider a sequence like $x = (\frac1n)_n \in A$, then for any $r>0$ the ball around $x$ contains sequences like $(y_n) = 1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots,-\frac r2, \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n+1}, \ldots$ that are not in $A$, so $x \notin \operatorname{int}(A)$.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating a bit ? I am very new to real analysis so .. :(

Comment: $A$ is open iff every point of it is an interior point. I just showed a point of $A$ that is not. Note that $d_\infty(x,y)$ only depends on one coordinate and by waiting till $\frac1n$ is really small, we can use the negative value while still maintaining a small distance to $x$.